# different behaviour of println() in java

Tags: java, println

```
//take the input from user
text = br.readLine();

//convert to char array
char ary[] = text.toCharArray();


System.out.println("initial string is:" + text.toCharArray());

System.out.println(text.toCharArray());
```

Output:

```
initial string is:[C@5603f377
abcd
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`println()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28char%5B%5D%29) is overloaded to print an array of characters as a string, which is why the 2nd print statement works correctly:

> `public void println(char[] x)`
>
> Prints an array of characters and then terminate the line. This method behaves as though it invokes [`print(char[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28char%5B%5D%29) and then [`println()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28%29).
>
> **Parameters:**
> `x` - an array of chars to print.

The 1st `println()` statement, on the other hand, concatenates the array's `toString()` with another string. Since arrays don't override `toString()`, they default to [`Object`'s implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29), which is what you see.